# Is there a Google Sheets formula that can take a range of cells, and list all the cells in one separate column, alphabetically?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If I have a range of cells and I want to list all the cells in one separate column, but ordered alphabetically.

I would think the `SORT` function would do the trick, but I'm seeing no way to do it. I also tried the `ARRAYFORMULA` function, to no avail.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A:A; A:A<>""))
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the quick response. So the trick is to first filter out empty cells, which defaults to alphabetical sorting? Also is there a way to change the sorting from A-Z, to Z-A?

Comment: sure. try: `=SORT(FILTER(A:A; A:A<>"");1;1)` or just `=SORT(A:A; 1;1)`

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't get that. Thanks. btw the semicolons are automatically replaced by commas in my Google Sheet.